# Adding subplot labels in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm creating a plot made up of smaller subplots using mfrow in par(), similarly to examples [here](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html).

Is there a way to add labels (A, B, C, ...) programmatically in the top corner of each of the subplots? Something like the letters in [this plot](https://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article/figure/image?size=large&id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1004126.g003).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can add text to the margin using the `mtext` function.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 2:5) {
    plot(mtcars[,c(1,i)], pch=20)
    mtext(LETTERS[i-1], adj=0, line=1)
}
```

[image: Plots with marginal text]